# Install package composer require yajra/laravel-oci8 but got some error

Tags: laravel

I want to install a package with `composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^8`. I'm using Laravel 8.10.0, it seems that the package supports that version but the following error appears:

How to solve this?

```
composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^8
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for yajra/laravel-oci8 8 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[v8.0.0].
    - yajra/laravel-oci8 v8.0.0 requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension oci8 is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: try to restart your pc some time it take time to effect `php.ini` changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to check with this PR and follow the instruction:

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/429